# Apache conditional config with if-else directives

Tags: apache-2.4, httpd.conf

Rather than commenting/uncommenting alternative configuration settings in my `httpd.conf` file, I would like to use something like this:

```
<If "0">
  # ...
</If>
<Else>
  # ...
</Else>
```

Of course, the expression in my `If` directive throws an error.  What would be the simplest expression to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<If "false">
...
</If>
```

See [Expressions in Apache HTTP Server](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html).

Comment: You don't appear to need to enclose `false` (or `true`) in quotes. (Works with or without.)